# Error in loops. and empty variable

Tags: python-2.7, loops

can anyone help me with the following 2 questions:

1) Considering the code below: If I print Listposblocks_COG1 it returns an empty variable. What am I doing wrong. Please note that the 'results'variable is much larger, but I only copied a short bit.

2) Considering the code below: If I print Listposblocks_COG2 or Listposblocks_COG3 Ireceive the error message: NameError: name 'Listposblocks_COG2' is not defined. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

```
#Only part of the table, but it would take too much space.   
    results = [[336350.0, 7089650.0, -7.0, 0.1665, 1.5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [336350.0, 7089650.0, -5.0, 0.1542, 1.5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [336350.0, 7089650.0, -3.0, 0.2259, 1.5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [336350.0, 7089650.0, -1.0, 0.2753, 1.5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

Start_index_nulzero = int(Length_Data_BM_Sorted)


if Start_index_nulzero == 5:
    Listposblocks_COG1 = []
    for i in results:
        if results[5] == 1:
            Listposblocks_COG1.append(i)


    if type(results[6]) == int:
        Listposblocks_COG2 = []
        for i in results:
            if results[6] == 1:
                Listposblocks_COG2.append(i)


    if type(results[7]) == int:
        Listposblocks_COG3 = []
        for i in results:
            if results[7] == 1:
                Listposblocks_COG3.append(i)

print Listposblocks_COG1
print Listposblocks_COG2
print Listposblocks_COG3
```

Comment: There's no printing statement in your code

Comment: In my real script there is. And it returns and empty Listposblocks_COG1, and it gives the error as named in question 2 for COG2 and COG3.

Comment: Why do you think those names should exist?

Comment: Then please add them to the code in your question, otherwise it is a bit hard to figure out what could have gone wrong

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Listposblocks_COG2, Listposblocks_COG3 I mean

@ Railslide: I thought I mentioned it in my text, but I will add it to the code. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable "results" is a list of lists so in this part

```
for i in results:
    if results[5] == 1:
        Listposblocks_COG1.append(i)
```

"results[5]" is probably never 1 so Listposblocks_COG1 is empty all the time.
Maybe you wanted to do this:

```
for i in results:
    if i[5] == 1:
        Listposblocks_COG1.append(i)
```

And probably the reason you can't print the other 2 lists is because they are in the "if" scope and you printed them out of there. So if you want to print them you should define them outside the "if" scope or put the print inside the "if".
Something like:

```
if Start_index_nulzero == 5:
    Listposblocks_COG1 = []
    for i in results:
        if i[5] == 1:
            Listposblocks_COG1.append(i)

    Listposblocks_COG2 = []
    if type(results[6]) == int:
        for i in results:
            if i[6] == 1:
                Listposblocks_COG2.append(i)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, results is already 1 in the first row. 

I want to add (append) the whole row  to Listposblocks_COG1 when there is a 1 in the column with index 5.

The print code is outside the if loop so it cannot be the problem.

Comment: Exactly, the print code is outside. But the list definition is inside. Have you tried with the code I posted? Because when you access results[5] you are accessing a list not a integer... So it's never 1. "results" is a list of lists. And you are doing for i in results and i[5] is the integer you actually want to search.

Comment: Thanks, indeed now I put in 'i' instead of 'results' it is working. However, why can't I print the Listposblocks_COG2 and Listposblocks_COG3. It should be saved in Listposblocks_COG2/3 right? And shouldn't I be able to print these lists at any time in the script in the future?